# Has Paypal changed or stopped using the https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb link to display Paypal buttons?

Tags: paypal

I am getting a broken image when I try https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamicimage.

This is the error message that comes back:

"Exception while trying to build protected config for application" and "failed to load cdb file /x/web/LIVE6-NONVERSIONED-640-20100706-1/WEB/fpdbs.paypal.com/cgi-bin/protected//client_sessions.cdb"

This is the raw output:

```
handler_cmd=_dispatch-failed&reason=Exception%20while%20trying%20to%20build%20protected%20config%20for%20application%3a%20ASF%3a%3aConfigureException%3a%20failed%20to%20load%20cdb%20file%3a%20/x/web/LIVE6-NONVERSIONED-640-20100706-1/web/fpdbs.paypal.com/cgi-bin/protected//client_sessions.cdb%20Backtrace%3a%2083e58fd%2083d1495%208425b41%20846a2af%2084627cf%208462cc5%20843154f%208058f51%208087926%208090902%2080654fc%20f6bbfe9c%2080578e1&failed_application=dynamicimageweb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct there was an issue with this.  We are currently working towards resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that the date this was asked (2nd May 2013) must have resolved, for a long while, but seems to be an issue again 19 June 2017.

This production url fails:
https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecmark&locale=en_GB

But the sandbox still returns a result:
https://fpdbs.sandbox.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecmark&locale=en_GB

Should we be using these instead?
https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/logos-buttons

If so, then we need to override the code within the Paypal Magento module (CE 1.8)

Comment: Concurring - Yep problem seems to have resolved their end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a transient server issue on Paypal's side rather than a change in the API programming.  The dynamic image URL works as expected now.  But I don't have any further details.

Answer (score 0):

I change in my store

For paypal express img in /app/design/fronted/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml

I edited this line , commented first line and added new picture fromo paypal website

```
    <!-- <img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl()?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Checkout with PayPal');?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Checkout with PayPal');?>" /> -->
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/buy-logo-small.png" alt="Buy now with PayPal" />
```

And for checkout commented and edit this line
/app/design/fronted/base/default/template/paypal/payment/mark.phtml

```
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-small.png" alt="Check out with PayPal" />
<!--<img src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc())?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::helper('paypal')->__('Acceptance Mark') ?>" class="v-middle" />&nbsp; -->
```